# Symfony2 customize checkbox form template

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am using bootstrap form theming. This is my fields.html.twig form template:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group {% if errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form, label|default(null), { 'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'} }) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {% set class='' %}
        {% if attr.class is defined %}
            {% set class = attr.class %}
        {% endif %}
        {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control '  ~ class} }) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

The problem is that it does not respect checkboxes. It renders checkboxes like normal input fields. Any idea how to setup a template for checkboxes based on the above template?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant `$builder->add` part where you add this form field? Do you have fields.html.twig defined in your `config.yml` as a `twig` resource?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás yeah everything works fine, only the checkbox is rendered with the above template. But the checkbox should get a different class, not .form-control but .checkbox

Comment: I don't understand why it shouldn't be rendered as the block above? You only pasted the form_row block. This *will* render all your form elements. Did you override any other blocks as well? Especially the ones for the checkbox? Are you adding the `attr[class]=checkbox` to your field?

Comment: @DebreczeniAndrás I just override form_row. The checkbox has to be rendered differently because it has another class and it has no wrapping div. Is there a chance to separate form_row and the checkbox template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the checkbox related blocks in your `fields.html.twig`. Depending on your field type (collapsed, expanded) define the following blocks:

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
    {% spaceless %}

    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}


{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
    {% spaceless %}

    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}

{# you can even override the way options are rendered #}
{% block choice_widget_options %}
    {% spaceless %}

    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_options %}
```

For the default implementation and the basis of your field templates can be acquired from the following location:
vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig